# Is it a good practice to restart VPS server everyday?

Tags: server, python, reboot, cache

I am building an app server using Ubuntu 20.04 and will be serving thousands of clients with potentially a million http messages everyday.
**I wanted to ask if it is a good practice to restart my server everyday at midnight?**
I think this will help release any memory issues, clear cache, etc. and make my server operate fast everyday.
I am getting this idea from using my laptop, performs really bad if I dont restart once a week.

Side question: How would one code this in Kotlin or Python (to restart the VPS and then launch my server .jar file after the restart)?

Comment: If you need to restart your server everyday to get rid of memory problems etc. it means your software is bad and has severe bugs. You should update it or replace your software by a better one that has no such bugs. Properly configured server should be able to run for months or even years without a need to restart.

Comment: 18.04 is no longer supported, and has entered ESM which is not covered on Ask Ubuntu per its current community guidelines and policy.  You should upgrade to at least 20.04 for your environment.

Comment: Updated the Ubuntu version to 20.0 @ThomasWard-OnStrike

Comment: I dont know if there are memory leaks or not yet as the app is not built yet. Just wanted to know whether its a normal thing or not to restart the server @raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This is a very bad practice.

As @raj states, a properly configured server running properly coded software should never have to be restarted, unless needed because of security updates.

So build your app without memory leaks, and you should be good.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I have no app code yet, just wanted to know if its a standard practices to restart the server every week. I got this idea because I need to restart my laptop once every week or its very slow!